# Tracking stack size during application execution

Tags: stack, powerpc

I am running an application on an embedded (PowerPC 32 bit) system where there is a stack size limitation of 64K. I am experiencing some occasional crashes because of stack overflow.

I can build the application also for a normal Linux system (with some minor little changes in the code), so I can run an emulation on my development environment.

I was wondering which is the best way to find the methods that exceed the stack size limitation and which is the stack frame when this happens (in order to perform some code refactoring).

I've already tried [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html%20%E2%80%9CCallgrind%E2%80%9D) (a Valgrind tool), but it seems not to be the right tool.

I'm looking more for a tool than changes in the code (since it's a 200K LOC and 100 files project).

The application is entirely written in C++03.

Comment: This is really abour PowerPC tools, not C++.

Comment: Couldn't you simply increase the stack size to a sufficiently large number? Most compilers let you do that (provided your platform has the memory needed, of course).

Comment: I know you say there's a 64k limit, but is that a *hard* limit or just what your default tool settings enforce?

Comment: It's an hard limit, I cannot change the stack size unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

While it seems that there should be an existing tool for this, I would approach it by writing a small macro and adding it to the top of suspected functions:

```
char *__stack_root__;

#define GUARD_SIZE (64 * 1024 - 1024)

#define STACK_ROOT \
    char __stack_frame__; \
    __stack_root__ = &__stack_frame__;

#define STACK_GUARD \
    char __stack_frame__; \
    if (abs(&__stack_frame__ - __stack_root__) > GUARD_SIZE) { \
        printf("stack is about to overflow in %s: at %d bytes\n", __FUNCTION__, abs(&__stack_frame__ - __stack_root__)); \
    }
```

And here how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    STACK_ROOT;                    // this macro records the top of the bottom of the thread's stack
    foo(10000);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int x) {
    STACK_GUARD;                   // this macro checks if we're approaching the end of memory available for stack
    if (x > 0) {
        foo(x - 1);
    }
}
```

couple notes here:

- this code assumes single thread.  If you have multiple threads, you need to keep track of individual `__stack_frame__` variables, one per thread.  Use thread local storage for this
- using `abs()` to make sure the macro works both when PowerPC grows its stack up, as well as down (it can: depends on your setup)
- adjust the GUARD_SIZE to your liking, but keep it smaller than the max size of your stack on the target

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, anyway that would require to change lot of code (I'm talking about a project of more than 100K LOC). I would prefer to have an external tool. Anyway I would also consider this solution.